# EXT.net.Mask.show position on page

Tags: extjs, ext.net

Looking to position an EXT.net  (based on EXT JS) with a message on the webpage so it is not the default of being centered.

```
e.g.

Ext.net.Mask.Show('Loading...');
```

version 1.6  http://examples1.ext.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question.

By default the Mask is forced to be centered, and there are no overrides, but you can reposition immediately upon showing.

**Example**

```
Ext.net.Mask.show({ msg : 'testing' });

Ext.fly(Ext.dom.Query.selectNode(".x-mask-msg")).setStyle({ top: "30px", left: "30px"});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm forced to use the old 1.6 version of EXT.NET, thus it is more difficult.   I see there is a DomQuery, but regardless of the Ext.dom.Query vs. Ext.DOMQuery  I get errors.  Can you show me a reference somewhere?  http://examples1.ext.net/  is what the existing team on the project told me to reference FYI ,  thanks in advance Geoffrey

Comment: Specifying Ext.NET version in a question is good. The code for Ext.NET v1: Ext.net.Mask.show({ msg : 'testing' }); 
Ext.fly(Ext.DomQuery.selectNode(".ext-el-mask-msg")).setStyle({ top: "30px", left: "30px"}); Sorry, it seems not to allow line breaks in the comments.

Comment: i added it to the question,  1.6   http://examples1.ext.net/   thx, I will look at this.